# How to get current location in android?

Tags: android, location

I am using the following code to get my current location, without GPS, but i want to show the co-ordinates in a toast. i have tried this code, but it shows my package name instead of co-ordinates!

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
          //makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
        }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "location is:"+locationListener, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Write Toast inside onLocationChanged(). Location. GetLat/LNG().

Comment: check this one out, it is really awesome https://github.com/meetmehdi/GetAccurateLocation

Comment: For those who are looking out for simple implementation to get the current/last known location, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761897/3908895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have the location in your `onLocationChanged()` callback.

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "location is:"+location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: can you tell me what line should i change to get the last known location instead?

Comment: Thats a different question. Accept an answer and create a new one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512349/how-do-i-get-my-last-known-location-in-android right here

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to toast the locationListener object.You have to craete a Location location; object and toast location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude() method while toasting.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code makes a toast when the LocationListener is registered, and calls Object.toString() on the listener, which just returns the class name of the listener.

You want to move the Toast.makeText(... line to inside the onLocationChanged function, and change the text to `"location is:"+location`, or maybe `"location is: "+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()`.

Also, this code will continue to make Toasts each time he gets a new location. You might want to either use LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate to only make a single toast, or put a LocationManager.removeUpdates in the onDestroy so that it stops when the activity is finished.

Comment: can you tell me what line should i change to get the last known location instead?

Comment: The requestLocationUpdates one. Get a list of providers with [one of the getProviders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders(boolean)) functions, then call [LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)). You'll have to write the logic which one to pick yourself, by comparing age or accuracy. You don't need the LocationListener if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

create     FMLocationListener  class first.

```
 private static class FMLocationListener implements LocationListener {

                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

        }
```

then use the following code

Comment: LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) act
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        FMLocationListener listenerNetwork = new FMLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
             LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listenerNetwork);
        Location networkLocation = getLocationByProvider(
             LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, locationManager);
    //toast using networkLocation .getLatityde() and getLongitude()

Comment: can you tell me what line should i change to get the last known location instead?