# How can I get my current location in Android using GPS?

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

> I want to get my current location in the form of an address by GPS. I am using the android studio.
>   It is saying that my application stops working.
>   What is the error in it?
>   Can someone help me to get out of this, please?

My Code in activity_main.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

My code in MainActivity.java is

```
package com.example.showlatlong;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Location gps_loc, network_loc, final_loc;
double longitude;
double latitude;
String userCountry, userAddress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }

    try {
        gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        network_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (gps_loc != null) {
        final_loc = gps_loc;
        latitude = final_loc.getLatitude();
        longitude = final_loc.getLongitude();
    }
    else if (network_loc != null) {
        final_loc = network_loc;
        latitude = final_loc.getLatitude();
        longitude = final_loc.getLongitude();
    }
    else {
        latitude = 0.0;
        longitude = 0.0;
    }

     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE}, 1);



    try {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            userCountry = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            userAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            tv.setText(userCountry + ", " + userAddress);
        }
        else {
            userCountry = "Unknown";
            tv.setText(userCountry);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

My code in manifest.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The entire code is this. It is opening the app and in less than a second, it is closing by throwing an error message that "app keeps stopping" on my android application.
This is what I got in the logcat is

```
2019-09-11 12:58:45.344 15400-15400/com.example.showlatlong E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.showlatlong, PID: 15400
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.showlatlong/com.example.showlatlong.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.showlatlong-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.showlatlong.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6857)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at 


 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit. 
 java:933)
 2019-09-11 12:58:45.344 15400-15400/com.example.showlatlong  
 E/AndroidRuntime:     
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Please show some code also what you have been tried so far

Comment: Natively you can only get coordinates using gps. You want to get Address like google maps?

Comment: @ArpitJ. I think it is possible to convert coordinates to show the location in google maps using reverse geocoding.

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales All the codes I have tried are not the recent versions and they are posted 3 years ago. So, I did not post the code. I am still a beginner and that made me ask you the process. Thankyou

Comment: For those who are looking out for simple implementation to get the current/last known location, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761897/3908895

Answer (score 10):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, you have to put this above or below the application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Because you did not show your code what you have been doing, so I have no clue how to resolve your problems. But the below code is the code I use for my application to get the current country of users.

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Location gps_loc;
        Location network_loc;
        Location final_loc;
        double longitude;
        double latitude;
        String userCountry, userAddress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }

        try {

            gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            network_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (gps_loc != null) {
            final_loc = gps_loc;
            latitude = final_loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = final_loc.getLongitude();
        }
        else if (network_loc != null) {
            final_loc = network_loc;
            latitude = final_loc.getLatitude();
            longitude = final_loc.getLongitude();
        }
        else {
            latitude = 0.0;
            longitude = 0.0;
        }


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE}, 1);

        try {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                userCountry = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                userAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                tv.setText(userCountry + ", " + userAddress);
            }
            else {
                userCountry = "Unknown";
                tv.setText(userCountry);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to ***understand this code***. One more thing, if you run your application on an emulator, it will keep showing "United States" or more specifically, Googleplex's location. Just run it on a real device to make it return your current location.

To return your current location other than just country itself, you can replace the

> addresses.get(0).getCountryName()

with something like

> addresses.get(0).getPostalCode()

or

> addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()

and so on.

You can too concatenate the values as a string to show your current location in detail.

Please have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address)

Comment: thankyou so much for that prompt reply. error: cannot find symbol variable countryAdapter 
error: cannot find symbol variable countryAdapter 
error: cannot find symbol variable countryEdit 
error: cannot find symbol variable countryEdit, I am getting these errors. Can you help me out please.

Comment: Look, my countryEdit variable is a spinner and the countryAdapter variable is ArrayAdapter<String>. Do you use a spinner by any chance? please let me know.

Comment: No, I did not use it anytime before. I just tried the code you sent me. Can you please tell me the entire code including activity.xml file. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: That's the only relevant code. I assume you are using a text view to do this, so I have changed it to text view instead of a spinner. If there is any mistake, tell me pls.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol variable text_view. I am now getting this. I have imported android.widget.textview also. What should I do now.

Comment: You must create the text view in an xml file by calling its id "text_view".

Comment: I have made the code clearer. Now you can have a look.

Comment: Yes. I've created Id as textview and it is working finally. But after opening the application, I'm not getting anything. Should I include any other buttons in text view?

Comment: No need. When you open your app, there should be a pop-up window asking you for accessing your location, then you must click "allow" otherwise it will return "Unknown".

Comment: There's no pop up window coming for me. It is saying that application keeps stopping. Can you please help me in doing it.

Comment: You missed the line "ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE}, 1);".

Comment: This is also a working one. Just Copy/Paste is enough

Comment: Still my application keeps stopping even after including the line.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: 2019-09-10 14:19:16.901 1498-1498/com.example.showlatlong E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
In terminal it is showing application has terminated. And in my android mobile, it is saying my application keeps stopping.

Comment: Can you try the code for getting the address using reverse geocoding?? If you already have an idea, can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you show your logcat when you run your app pls.

Comment: Can you please see it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google's Fused Location Profivider API](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/?source=post_page-----1001eb549089----------------------) library to get and access your current location (given that your GPS service is turned on)

Also don't forget to add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

For a more detailed tutorial you can refer at this [Medium GPS Tutorial](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/getting-gps-location-on-android-with-fused-location-provider-api-1001eb549089)

Cheers

Comment: depending on device, this may not be the best idea.  My work manages 600 tablets that don't get software through the play store,and fused location provider relies on play services, which google forces you to update often.  If you don't, you lose play services which breaks fuse location provider.  We had to manually update 600 tablets.

Comment: Yes. But in most cases this is a best plan if you are developing the norm. In your case you can use the native LocationManager to access GPS data

Comment: like i said, depends on device.  Note that i've also seen a tablet (specifically the new tab a from samsung) that we had to disable every location source besides gps because it was screwing it up.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @JohnLord, if not use `Fused Location Profivider` and update Play Services seldom (or never), will `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` work well?

Comment: i would think so.  All the google play wrapper does is add some events for you to use and auto-switches to the best current location.  This could conceivably be wifi if you are in a city.  Note that the underlying behavior depends on the OS version.  Newer ones only trigger new points when you are moving or when they get around to giving you a point vs when you ask for it.  It prevents bogging the system down.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below way here you can get location using the gps and network both

```
 public class LocationTracker {

    public static String TAG = LocationTracker.class.getName();

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location = null;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    static Context mcontext;
    private static LocationTracker instance;


    public static synchronized LocationTracker getInstance(Context ctx) {
        mcontext = ctx;
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LocationTracker();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    myListener listener;
    public void connectToLocation(myListener listener) {
        this.listener=listener;
        stopLocationUpdates();
        displayLocation();
    }

    private void displayLocation() {
        try {
            Logger.i(TAG,"displayLocation");
            Location location = getLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                updateLattitudeLongitude(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
        }
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mcontext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                this.canGetLocation = false;

            } else {

                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    Logger.d(TAG + "-->Network", "Network Enabled");

                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationProviderListener);
                        return location;
                    }

                } else if (isGPSEnabled) {

                    Logger.d(TAG + "-->GPS", "GPS Enabled");

                    if (locationManager != null) {

                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationProviderListener);

                        return location;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
        }
        return location;
    }

    public void updateLattitudeLongitude(double latitude, double longitude) {
        Logger.i(TAG, "updated Lat == " + latitude + "  updated long == " + longitude);
        SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager = SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance();
        sharedPreferenceManager.updateUserDeviceLatLong(latitude, longitude);

    
    listener.onUpdate(latitude, longitude);
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates(){
        try {
            if (locationManager != null) {
                Logger.i(TAG,"stopLocationUpdates");
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationProviderListener);
                locationManager = null;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public LocationListener locationProviderListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            try {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                updateLattitudeLongitude(latitude, longitude);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {


        }
    };

   Public interface myListener{
       onUpdate(double latt,double longg)
    }

}
```

**From Activity**

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{

 void startLication(){
 LocationTracker.getInstance(this).connectToLocation(new myListener(){


     @override
     void onUpdate(double latt,double longg){

         //Here you can get
    }

   });
  }
}
```

Comment: please also mention how to use it in a activity so that it helps everyone

Comment: Just try to use..... LocationTracker.getInstance(this). connectToLocation();... from activity......you can also extend or add with your interface listener to update this from updateLattitudeLongitude  method to update in ui/activity class.

Comment: Can you add it to your answer

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal  please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class in the Android framework location APIs, you can convert an address to the corresponding geographic coordinates. This process is called geocoding. Alternatively, you can convert a geographic location to an address. The address lookup feature is also known as reverse geocoding.

Use [getFromLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) method to convert a geographic location to an address. The method returns an estimated street address corresponding to a given latitude and longitude.

```
public List<Address> getFromLocation (double latitude, double int maxResults)
```

This Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude. The returned addresses will be localized for the locale provided to this class's constructor.

Take a look here as well: https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address

Answer (score 0):

Try This! (Did it one year back)- Will update your location on all your move at certain interval.

Add dependencies in grade

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

Add permissions in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In Your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    TextView tv;
    Context context;

    Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        tv = findViewById(R.id. text_view);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        initLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100000); // Update location every second
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            setValue();
        }
    }

    private void setValue() {
        String strAddress =  getAddressFromLocation(this, latitude, longitude);
        tv.setText(strAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            else
            {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        initLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private void initLocation() {

        if(checkAndRequestPermissions(context)) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Permission Granded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(Context context) {

        int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static String getAddressFromLocation(Context context, final double latitude, final double longitude) {
        String straddress = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if(address.getAddressLine(0) !=null && address.getAddressLine(0).length()>0 && !address.getAddressLine(0).contentEquals("null"))
                {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(0)).append("\n");
                }else {

                    sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                }
                straddress = sb.toString();
                //Log.e("leaddress","@"+straddress);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
        }
        return straddress;
    }
}
```